# Drupal 8 '"views_get_current_view " returns null

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have placed the following function in my ".module " file to get the information of current view. But it returns null

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $record = array();
    $view = views_get_current_view();
}
```

I have added `use Drupal\views\Views;` in the top.

What could be the reason to return null ? Am I missing anything?

**Update**

I have search form in the top. I want to have a form at bottom to search within the search result. So I need the data given in the actual search form.

So a module has been created in drupal 7 and it is working perfectly. I want to create the same module in drupal 8 as we are upgrading the site.

But some of the functions are not working in drupal 8 like `drupal_get_form('my_search_secondary_exposed_form')`.

So instead of `drupal_get_form` i am using

`$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\searchrefine\Form\SearchrefineForm');`

Inside this form i need to take the details of actual search form. So i am trying to use `views_get_current_view`. But that does not work.

Comment: Views::views_get_current_view(); might work, not exactly sure what you're trying to do or how ...

Comment: Can is use `get_current_view` inside forms? that is `mymodule/src/Forms/myForm.php  buildForm()` method

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder::getForm/8.2.x

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182405/how-to-render-form-in-drupal-8